# Why can't I toggle checkboxes on Jenkins plugin manager

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use the [Reverse Proxy Auth Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Reverse+Proxy+Auth+Plugin) for Jenkins.  When I try to use the "HTTP Header by reverse proxy" security realm option in the "Configure Global Security" section of Manage Jenkins I get the following stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.reverse_proxy_auth.ReverseProxySecurityRealm
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.dispatch(MetaClass.java:380)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.reverse_proxy_auth.ReverseProxySecurityRealm
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.invokeConstructor(RequestImpl.java:523)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:775)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.access$200(RequestImpl.java:81)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:672)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:476)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:472)
at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:588)
at hudson.DescriptorExtensionList.newInstanceFromRadioList(DescriptorExtensionList.java:140)
at hudson.DescriptorExtensionList.newInstanceFromRadioList(DescriptorExtensionList.java:144)
at hudson.security.GlobalSecurityConfiguration.configure(GlobalSecurityConfiguration.java:95)
at hudson.security.GlobalSecurityConfiguration.doConfigure(GlobalSecurityConfiguration.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:320)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:163)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
... 64 more
```

Searching yielded this [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24780) which suggests enabling the LDAP plugin.  The Jenkins plugin manager interface has checkboxes to indicate status (a plugin is enabled if the box is checked).

The Reverse Proxy Auth Plugin box is checked, but the mouseover dialog box indicates that the plugin cannot be enabled:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE0MK.png]

It also says that the LDAP plugin is disabled, but the LDAP plugin menu item suggests that it is enabled in the mouseover text, while the checkbox indicates it is disabled:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUbGc.png]

Both checkboxes are also greyed out, meaning I can't see if there is a difference when enabling/disabling either plugin.  This, with a combination of the conflicting information shown in the images, makes it difficult for me to determine what is actually happening.

So why are the boxes greyed out?

UPDATE:  This seems to be an open [issue (JENKINS-32580)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32580) on jenkins tracker.
[JENKINS-21486](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21486) is also related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue recently with another group of plugins recently. One wouldn't allow me to disable it because it dependeded on the other, but the other was disabled and wouldn't allow me to enable it because of the dependency.

All you have to do to fix this is go to your jenkins installation, and under the plugins directory look for the plugin_name.jpi file. For the disabled plugin, you should see a file called plugin_name.jpi.disabled. Just delete the disabled file and then you should be able to enable / disable the plugins through the UI.

Note: you can also manually disable plugins by creating a disabled plugin file using the naming convention above.

Comment: accepted as correct answer for Jenkins 1.651.2, Ldap plugin 1.12,  
Reverse Proxy Auth Plugin 1.5